# Migrate Rhythbox from one computer to another with different username

Tags: rhythmbox

I want to migrate Rhythmbox from one computer to another. I have different usernames in both the computers.

I will need to carry music files, covers, playcounts, ratings, playlists, etc.

Merely copying music files and .local/share/rhythmbox does not work (I guess because Music locations are different on both the computers).

What is the best way to achieve this? I will at least like to carry ratings and playlists.

Comment: Which version of rhythmbox are you using? For album covers u can easily copy `~/.cache/rhythmbox/covers` folder.  For other thing you need to edit `rhythmdb.xml` file under `~/.local/share/rhythmbox` & replace the location for each file .Use gedit's find & replace utility. For other settings you can try moving ~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should copy over /home/user/.local/share

use emacs or another good text editing, to search all files and subfolder for the location of the components from the first node to the second and do a mass replace. that'll take care of a lot of the problems.

- the covers, copy them over from ~/.cache/rhythmbox/covers, but honestly, if you don't have international music or albums no one ever heard of, the software's auto fetch covers is enough
- music files can be literally copied over manually
- /home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox/playlists.xml (you can edit files location to the songs)
- ratings and playcounts are in /home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhytmdb.xml you can rebuild your entire library from this file, as long as the locations are consistent.
- For other settings you can try moving ~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox. (depends on the version though )

Credits to  Khurshid, he uncovered couple of the points.